# GUI Framework Used in Opera Mobile/Mini Android Application

Tags: android, user-interface, frameworks, opera

I have never seen this type of **`EditText`**, **`Toggle Button`** and **`Bottom Bar Button`** used by Opera Mobile / Mini in other applications on Android. I want to know which GUI framework they have used to build such a great cross platform UI application?. Is there any open source framework available for this or they have used their own proprietary. Also I want to know how can we develop such a great user interface based applications?.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a custom framework, see [the press release](http://www.opera.com/press/releases/2009/12/10/) for what is public about it.